# Cannot find -lc and -lm in g++ linux

Tags: gcc, include, g++

I am using Ubuntu and gcc and g++ were working fine but today it showed:

```
cannot find -lm
cannot find -lc
```

I searched and found it has something to do with `/usr/bin/ld`. Which is a symlink (I hope) to `lbd.bdf`. I pasted that file in the directory from Ubuntu of some friends PC. It didn't work.

I found that `-lc` means include static library libc.a.
similarly for `-lm`

I found them in my `i386-linux-folders` (name was something different).

I tried code blocks but same errors.

Comment: what is your g++ command line?

Comment: Do a reinstall of development packages (e.g. aptitude remove build-essential; reboot; aptitude install build-essential)

Comment: @KevinDTimm g++ -o output_fileName cpp_fileName

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure that your libpath (in g++) points to the directory(ies) that libm.a and libc.a are located in (use the -L option)

Comment: How to view current libpath of my g++?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I never did that before and it worked fine... Now what is the need ? always did g++ -o output_fileName cpp_fileName. Worked fine.

Comment: Your LIBRARY_PATH is fouled up (see http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc, search for LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: If liba and libm are not in the default location then there is a bigger problem. Setting -L is unlikely to help.

Comment: I m sorry if i sounded like that.. but i think you are right about LIBRARY_PATH . echo ${LIBRARY_PATH} showed nothing. and libc.a is at  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xen/libc.a and libm.a is at            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xen/libm.a

Comment: So, if you update LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, does your compilation work?

Comment: My LIBRARY_PATH was distorted.

    export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

well the value of path would depend upon your libc.a and libm.a file location.

Thanks to KevinDTimm

Answer (score 34):

The compiler cannot find static glibc, you might have installed only the shared libraries, try:

`yum install glibc-static`

Answer (score 0):

`ld` is the GNU linker.

`man ld`
       ld combines a number of object and archive files, relocates their data and ties up symbol references. Usually the last step in compiling a program is to run ld.

It is uses to link your program with the C library and the C math library. You need to make sure that `libc6-dev` is installed:

```
foo@bar: $ dpkg -s libc6-dev
```

Or more generic, ensure `build-essential`, which depends on a handful of essential C packages.

```
foo@bar: $ dpkg -s build-essential
```

Comment: note that the OP has no concept of `ld`. When you talk only about `ld` the onus is on you to explain to him how these (`g++` and `ld`) are related.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Same for libpath, eh? Well, I don't know how much of programming and *nix the OP understands already, but if you get a basic book on C++, it usually exaplains the concepts behind compilation (basically preprocessing, compiling, linking). I think if you read such book, then reading `ld is the linker`, than it will already be of help.